# Has FAA published any A-RNP STAR or A-RNP / RNP AR DP SID?

Tags: faa-regulations, usa, sid-star, performance-based-navigation, rnp

After reading *FAA*'s [Performance Based Navigation Strategy 2016](https://www.faa.gov/nextgen/media/PBN_NAS_NAV.pdf), I tried to search for already published Departure Procedures of RNP specification. I could only find some that require RNP-1, even though they seem to be rare, like [STAYY ONE](https://aeronav.faa.gov/d-tpp/1904/00377stayy.pdf#nameddest=(SNA)) (KSNA airport).

My question is, are there any SIDs of A-RNP or RNP AR DP specification or STARs of A-RNP specification officially published, at least as far as *FAA*'s charts are concerned?

Comment: Did you look for procedures here or someplace else?  https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/dtpp/

Comment: @CrossRoads thank you for your input, I have already used the link you specified in order to search for FAA's published Departure and Arrival Procedures. I also checked the Coded Instrument File Procedures (CIFP) file provided by FAA. My understanding is that no A-RNP or RNP AR DP procedures (SID or STAR) have been published yet.